# TPTP equivalent for Eclipse 4 (Kepler)

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, memory, analysis

I would like to measure the memory usage over time of some eclipse plugins we develop. Searching over the internet, 2 projects are often mentioned: Eclipse Memory Analyzer and TPTP.

I feel that memory analyzer will provide some information about number of objects and size from the start of our application to the moment the Heap dump is created. This can be useful, but I would like to see the evolution of memory usage over time. Something similar to
[image: from eclipsezone] (http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t52038.html)

The TPTP project (https://www.eclipse.org/tptp/index.php) has been discontinued, so my question is: Is there a project similar to TPTP, which can be used in Eclipse Kepler ?

Or maybe that I search to is reachable with Eclipse Memory Analyzer. I didn't succeed to get this kind of information.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience there are three free ways to go on this:

1.- JConsole

2.- Jvisualvm

Both of these can be found on any Hotspot JVM distribution in SDK.

And number three, which I would deffinetly go for detailed analysis:

3.- JVM Option : XX:+PrintGCDetails. This way you will get as raw as you can since the garbage collector will be logging all of its activities, including Heap section sizes and garbage collection (both minor and major) invocations and timings. You can use Xloggc: to redirect the output.